# Divide a file by region and save to one array

Tags: where-clause, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to divide a file by numpy or pandas. I have a several regions that I want to have as an end product and save it into one file.

```
sel_a_A = np.where((a[:,0]>100.)&(a[:,0]<=150.))
sel_a_B = np.where((a[:,0]>146.)&(a[:,0]<=149.))
sel_a_C = np.where((a[:,0]>161.)&(a[:,0]<=189.))
```

This works okay but for only one region at a time. When I tried to apply it for the whole data set at one:

```
in_one = np.where(
(a[:,0]>100.)&(a[:,0]<=150.) & (a[:,0]>146.) &(a[:,0]<=149.)
& (a[:,0]>161.)&(a[:,0]<=189.)
)
```

I received empty array.
Maybe `where` is not a good option. If there are any recommendations, please let me know.